# How to change date format in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

Scenario:

I have a data_value in field input_date as: 30/06/2020 13:40
How can I test another div contains the same value in another format - 23rd June 2020 13:40

```
const inp_date = cy.get('input_date').invoke('val')
cy.get('div').should('contain', inp_date)
```

How will I format inp_date so that it is in the format 23rd June 2020 13:40

NOTE:  input_date and  are in two different pages. Means, When I am in the page where I need to test the div, input will not be available

[image]

Comment: I suspect you should be using an alias rather than a variable to hold the date from `input_date`, see [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context).

Comment: To get a complete picture, please post the whole test including how you transition to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer: [Cypress includes moment.js](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/moment.html#Syntax)

I have used `Cypress.env` to transfer data between pages for validation.

#### `Page 1:`

**Markup**:

```
<input type="text" id="input_date" value="30/06/2020 13:40" />
```

#### `Page 2:`

**Markup**:

```
<div>23rd June 2020 13:40</div>
<div>30th June 2020 13:40</div>
```

**Test**:

```
cy.get('#input_date').then(($el) => {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const formattedDate = Cypress.moment($el.val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format('Do MMMM YYYY HH:mm');
        if (formattedDate) {
            resolve(formattedDate);
        } else {
            reject(0); // handle reject;
        }
    })
}).then(formattedDate => {
    Cypress.env('inputDate', formattedDate);
    cy.log('created new user on ' + Cypress.env('inputDate'));
});

cy.wait(0);
cy.log('created new user on ' + Cypress.env('inputDate'));
cy.wait(1000);
cy.log('created new user on ' + Cypress.env('inputDate'));
cy.visit('http://localhost:8081/page2');
cy.get('div').should('contain', Cypress.env('inputDate'));
```

[image: Screenshot from my test]

Comment: Thank you. But forgot to mention that  <input> tag and <div> are in two different pages. Means, When I am in the page where I need to test the div, input will not be available. Is there any solution for this? I will update my question

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution that I am using in my tests.

Comment: Should  cy.config('inputDate', formattedDate); be Cypress.config? cy.config is not a function :)

Comment: cy.get('#input_date').then($el => {
  const formattedDate = Cypress.moment($el.val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format('Do MMMM YYYY HH:mm');
  cy.config('inputDate', formattedDate);cy.log('created new user on'+ Cypress.config('inputDate'))// working inputDate gives me correct value
}); Cypress.config('inputDate')) // not working outside gives undefined

Comment: Cypress.config('inputDate')) // not working outside gives undefined

Comment: `cy.config` was a typo. Should be `Cypress.config`. Outside of `then` it will be asynchronous so you may need to add a`wait`. But in second page, it will work. Updated my answer.

Comment: After adding wait also, it is still showing undefined and in the next page also it shows undefined. Added the screenshot along with the question

Comment: @AJ: It seems in my test scenarios, I have set the required data in config from `xhr` responses. I assumed the `cy.get().then()` also automatically gets resolved via `Cypress.Promise` which is not the case so we need to explicitly wrap in `Cypress.Promise`, hence the data was not available globally in my last answer version.
I have updated the answer again but this time I recreated your exact scenario of two pages and have attached screenshot. Hope this time my answer finally helps! :)

Comment: Hi I was not working on this test and recently I came back to finish the test and found something very annoying. The time is not set properly. sometimes, the inputDate has a value that is  10 mins less than what is in the textbox. Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: @ Sree.Bh any idea?

Comment: I had come across a similar problem with `chai` and the discrepancy was when the test ran on Jenkins versus in my local. Are you observing the difference in your local test?

Comment: It is reproducible in my local. Since it is happening in local, I haven't added the test to CI